# ASP.NET - GridView - EditItem - Null Value for Integers?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a GridView in asp.net 2.0 and I want to perform inline editing. I am using an object datasource. Because I want to use validation controls on the integer fields in my gridview, I have made them into `<TemplateFields>` and added a datatype validator and a range validator. This allows me to either have a blank field, or an integer value between 0 and 999.

I am trying to display a "-" when the value of the property is not defined. There is no Null for an integer, so I have decided to use -1 as the value to indicate a Null.

I am reformatting the  to display the "-" if the value is -1.  I do that as follows:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblPC" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatIntegerToText(Eval("PitchCount"),"-") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the code behind I have defined the function FormatIntegerToText as follows:

```
Protected Function FormatIntegerToText(ByVal value As Object, ByVal nullvalue As String) As String
       ' Make sure value is not null... if so, return "-"
       If value = Null.NullInteger() Then
           Return nullvalue
       Else
           Return value.ToString()
       End If
End Function
```

All of this works great. Now comes the problem...when I click my Edit button, the `<EditItem>` is displayed (with textboxes etc) but all the "null" values are displayed as -1

I currently have this as my `<EditItemTemplate>`

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:textbox ID="txtPC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PitchCount") %>' width="25" Columns="2"></asp:textbox>
   ....a couple of validators....
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I though I could do the following to reformat the value that is placed in the text box:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:textbox ID="txtPC" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatIntegerToText(Bind("PitchCount")) %>' width="25" Columns="2"></asp:textbox>
```

but when I do this I get a compilation error that Bind is not a recognized function.

My question is, why is this not allowed, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this differently.  Instead of using a bound column, create a template column... that will give you full control over the content, and allow you to write a function to format the text during display as well as set the contents to the appropriate value when editing.

Answer (score 0):

Bind is not really a function, that's why you get compilation error. More details are at [Eilon Lipton's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx).

Try replacing Bind with Eval.

You also would need to store new value in RowUpdating event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   e.NewValues["PitchCount"] =
      ((TextBox)((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPC")).Text;
}
```

---

Another approach is to use [nullable type](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2004/05/28/143813.aspx). Instead of Integer use `Nullable(Of Integer)`. Then, use [NullDisplayText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext.aspx) to show “-” instead of NULL:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PitchCount" NullDisplayText="-" HeaderText="PitchCount"
  SortExpression="PitchCount />
```